# Around the same time every night my site hangs. Other times it loads normally. Help!

Tags: server

I hope this is the right place for this type of question.

Around 7 or 8pm (Japan time) my site will hang or time out when accessed about 75% of the time. 25% of the time, it responds normally. This issue always happens around the same time.

Server stats show no real increase in traffic.
Server logs show no strange users interacting with the site.

Any advice on what might be happening and how I can begin to deal with it?

Thanks,
Benjamin

Comment: Is it the exact same time every day?

Answer (score 2):

If it's happening at exactly the same time every day, probably some scheduled background task is running and taking up a lot of resources (CPU/RAM or disk IO) or locking database tables. Maybe backups or some kind of cleanup script.

Is it shared hosting server, VPS or dedicated server? On shared server it may be caused by some other user.

If you have direct (ssh?) access to the server, you can run tools like htop or iotop to see what's running. Also check scheduled cron tasks, if there's anything running around that time. On shared hosting probably the only thing you can do is contact server admin.

What's in the error logs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feel uncomfortable saying it's happening at exactly the same time, as we are usually busy during the day and then start to notice the issue. I will try to time it in the future.

Comment: It's a VPS, but I don't have SSH access. 

In the cpanel whm process manager however, I have found this:

/usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=benchan.benchaneikaiwa.com.err --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=benchan.benchaneikaiwa.com.pid

Could this be it?